# Google Actions Account Linking: doesn't work in testing

Tags: oauth, actions-on-google, account-linking

I have to develop a Google Action with a mandatory Account Linking phase that I have configured with an OAuth2 server. I'm using the online console at https://console.actions.google.com/ to develop the action.

I have set up the Start scene where the condition is `user.validationStatus != "VERIFIED"` . Based on the result of the condition I will go to 2 different scenes.

Here the screen of the Start scene where is checked the account linking status.
[image: Start scene]

Here the Start_AccountLinking scene
[image: Account linking scene]

But when I try to go in the "Test" section of the console after I open the action with the invocation, It doesn't pass any of the conditions and stays in the Start scene. In the log on the right, I can see that it failed both the conditions.

```
{
  "conditionsEvaluated": {
    "failedConditions": [
      {
        "expression": "user.validationStatus != \"VERIFIED\"",
        "nextSceneId": "Start_AccountLinking"
      },
      {
        "expression": "user.validationStauts == \"VERIFIED\"",
        "nextSceneId": "AuthenticatedScene"
      }
    ]
  },
  "responses": [
    {
      "firstSimple": {
        "speech": "Benvenuto in Semiperdo",
        "text": "Benvenuto in Semiperdo"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have to elaborate @Stefano. Android/iOS? Share code?

Comment: I have added information on the problem, thanks @TomerPetel

Comment: Sorry for not replying @Stefano, I thought you're talking about account linking in iOS/Android apps using AppFlip.

Comment: @StefanoMoro can you please provide me any document with examples for account linking? I have facing one issue, after click `Yes` for account linking it will show this message `Sorry, something went wrong, so I couldn't sign you in. But you can try again later.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **user.validationStatus** use **user.accountLinkingStatus**. It will work!

Comment: Now it works, thank you so much! But do I have to complete the linking using the Google Home App also if I'm still testing it in the console?

Comment: @StefanoMoro Yes, since you set your scenes in that way. But you don't need to go for Google Home App for account linking. you can go to your actions in (assistant [dot] google [dot] com / explore) website and do the account linking process.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you're using `user.accountLinkingStatus` the value you're looking for is "LINKED", not "VERIFIED". I.e. `if user.accountLinkingStatus == 'LINKED'`.